# Make object face and move towards player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

Im making a simple 2d ship game for my school project. Right now the ai will face the player and follow them at a certain distance, then when close enough, rotate so that it can fire at the player from each side of the ship. But with my current code the enemy will move sideways towards the player at the firing range, which obviously shouldn't happen.

So how can i make the enemy only move forwards and remain perpendicular to the player.

Here is my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed, stopD, retreatD, Chase_range, distance,firing_range;
    // declare player and enemy as transform to retrieve their positions
    public Transform player;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();

        Chase_range = 14;
        firing_range = 10;
        stopD = 6;
        retreatD = 4;

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        // Distance between the enemy and player positions
        distance = (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position));
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (distance > stopD)
        {
            // move towards the player if the distance is greater than stop distance
            speed = 10;

        }
        else if (distance < stopD & distance > retreatD)
        {
            speed = 0;
        }
        else if (distance < retreatD)
        {
            // move away from the player if the distance is less than stop distance (avoid collision)
            speed = -10;
        }

        if (distance > Chase_range)
        { 
         // have to use vector3 since vector2 does not work with the z axis
         // calculate the difference in the position vectors
         Vector3 vectorToTarget = player.position - transform.position;
            // Calculate the angle between the objects and convert the result to degrees
         float angle = Mathf.Atan2(vectorToTarget.y, vectorToTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            // convert the angle into a quaternion so that it can be used by slerp 
         Quaternion playerq = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);

         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, playerq, Time.deltaTime * speed);      
        }
        if (distance < firing_range)
        {
            float Rfactor;
            Vector3 vectorToTarget = player.position - transform.position;

            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(vectorToTarget.y, vectorToTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            if (angle < 0) 
            {
                Rfactor = 90;
            }
            else if (angle > 0)
            {
                Rfactor = -90;
            }
                Quaternion playerq = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle + Rfactor, Vector3.forward);
            
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, playerq, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }

    }
```

And don't mind the shitty comments, its for school.
Any other comments about the code would also be greatly appreciated

Comment: you might be using the forward attribute on the wrong axis, but i don't really understand what is the problem, could you clarify?

Comment: Well the code so far functions as intended, the enemy rotates and moves towards the player at a certain distance and then when it gets closer rotates so that it is perpendicular to the player. What i need to do now is make it so that the enemy will travel alongside the player so that they can keep firing.

Comment: Could you try and add an offset to his movement to the axis that you like?

Answer (score 0):

With some quick googling I found this answer:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1125044/how-do-i-move-an-object-relative-to-another-object.html

Using this you can move the enemy forward relative to the player. If you rotate the player now you will have the desired result: the enemy will move with the player but stay focused on it